# How to make emacs respect non-exe executables on windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, cygwin

I've installed flake8 for flycheck to use to check my python syntax. I installed flake8 in cygwin, using the python interpreter shipped with cygwin, which results in a `flake8` file in `C:\cygwin64\bin`. The problem is, emacs seems to only respect exe files so if I `(executable-find "flake8")` it yields `nil`. I had the same problem when I enabled anaconda-mode, since cygwin has `python2.7.exe` and `python` in `C:\cygwin64\bin`. I solved this by copy `python2.7.exe` to `python.exe`, but the flake8 problem can't be solved this way.

I `vim /usr/bin/flake8`d, turns out it's really `flake.py` with python code inside to run with python.

**tl;dr**: Generally the question is: How to make emacs aware of "excutables" that would normally run by `python flake8.py`, `node eslint.js`? (When I used eslint with flycheck for js-file syntax check, it just works, maybe there's the solution?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was long ago since I last used Cygwin, but I don't think this is the reason. `executable-find` uses its own "database" of locations to look at for executables. I believe the variable is `exec-path`. Look at its current value. If it doesn't contain `C:\cygwin64\bin`, `append-to-list` it.

Comment: @wvxvw Checked, "C:/cygwin64/bin" is present.

Comment: @wvxvw I solved it myself with some luck, you may want to check it out.

Comment: Aha, I see.  Yes, this would totally make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: `cp path/to/eslint.cmd /usr/bin/flake8.cmd`, then `vim flake8.cmd`, edit exe and script names inside.

How I found that: I gave a second thought to "why eslint just works?" Because it's `eslint.js`? I changed `flake8` to `flake8.py`, no luck. Thanks to `everything`, I typed `eslint.` in the search bar, and `eslint.cmd` stood out. Then I cloned it to `flake8.cmd` and problem's solved. I tried in both cygwin and dos terminals, `flake8` can be invoked just like a command/exe. So I guess for everyone under Windows, the definition for "executable" is the same: `.exe`s and `.cmd`s (and some others).

Comment: The list of "others" is in `exec-suffixes`.